# Uploading a Flutter project to Github using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github, flutter

I am creating an app using Flutter with Andriod Studio. I am trying to upload a project to GitHub using the VCS 'Import into Version Control' to create a repository for the program but it keeps getting stuck with an error saying that the file is too big to upload to GitHub. I'm not sure why this is the case as it's not a very large program and I've cloned a file similar in size to this one from GitHub before.

(I'm using a MacBook Pro)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Also here is the flutter doctor output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.5 at /Users/AdamWood/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 1aedbb1835 (9 weeks ago), 2019-10-17 08:37:27 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/AdamWood/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3, Build version 11C29
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try to import the proyect with nothing, and make your first commit with all the proyect files